# UCP jar dependency present in pom.xml but its not appearing inside WEB-INF\lib

Tags: java, xml, maven

As I said in the title that, i have included the ucp jar dependency inside MyProject\pom.xml but that jar file is not present inside `MyProject\target\MyProject\WEB-INF\lib`. What might be the reason behind this?

POM Entry :

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependencies with scope `provided` are not included in your war, they are only available during compile and test phase. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope